# Strange bug with define_singleton_method and keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I stumbled upon what I believe to be a weird bug in Ruby (I'm using 2.2.2).

When I define a method like so:

```
def test(value, **kw)
  puts value
  puts kw
end
```

I get the expected output:

```
> test(1)
1
{}
=> nil

> test(1, channel: 'active')
1
{:channel=>"active"}
=> nil

> test(1, channel_s: 'active')
1
{:channel_s=>"active"}
=> nil

> test(1, channel_st: 'active')
1
{:channel_st=>"active"}
=> nil

> test(1, channel_sta: 'active')
1
{:channel_sta=>"active"}
=> nil

> test(1, channel_stat: 'active')
1
{:channel_stat=>"active"}
=> nil

> test(1, channel_state: 'active')
1
{:channel_state=>"active"}
=> nil
```

But when I define an equivalent method with define_singleton_method:

```
define_singleton_method(:test_2) do |value, **kw|
  puts value
  puts kw
end
```

I get a very peculiar result when a keyword is exactly 'channel_type':

```
> test_2(1)
1
{}
=> nil

> test_2(1, channel_state: 'active')

{:channel_state=>"active"}
=> nil

> test_2(1, channel_stat: 'active')
1
{:channel_stat=>"active"}
=> nil

> test_2(1, channel_states: 'active')
1
{:channel_states=>"active"}
=> nil

> test_2(1, channel_state: nil)

{:channel_state=>nil}
=> nil
```

Has anyone seen this before? Maybe with a different keyword?

**Edit:** This appears to only be affecting my ruby on rails application being run within a docker container. If someone can reproduce, please comment below!

Comment: Very weird. I just tried it on 2.2.3 and couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Ditto... can't reproduce under 2.2.3.

Comment: Maybe it's just 2.2.2? I tried it on 2.3 and couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Actually, here's another update: might only be related to docker! I've been running this on a docker image (the ruby-2.2.2) and it only appears to be affecting that. Straight irb did not do it.

Comment: I'm using docker image for ruby 2.3 now and it works. I'm baffled.

Comment: Cant reproduce in Ruby 2.3

Comment: Sorry, but what is tbe issue?